# Purpose of const byte for setting keypad position

Tags: c++, arduino, keypad

```
const byte rows = 4;  //number of rows on the keypad
const byte cols = 4;  //number of columns on the keypad 
char keypressed;
char keyMap[rows][cols]={  //keymap defines the key pressed on the keypad according to the rows and columns on the keypad
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'} 
};
```

Can someone explain what is the purpose of having byte and char in `const byte rows=4` and `char keyMap[rows][cols]`?

Answer (score 0):

It declares the type of the variable.

const byte cols = 4; defines a constant byte value named cols with value 4.

`char keyMap[rows][cols] = { ... }`  defines a two dimensional array with rows * cols char values.

Read https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/char/